# JavaScript Validation (Colorbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, colorbox

In my page I have three fields that is required to fill in. If they are filled in a small pop up opens for registration.  However, right now I have it in JavaScript. If one or more filed is not filled in, it will give a message one after other. For example, field 1,2,3 are not filled in. It will tell in a message box, please fill in field 1, second pop up please fill in 2 field, and please fill in 3 field.  And right after it opens the registration pop up.  I want to prevent that, UNLESS all the fields are filled in. It SHOULD NOT open the pop up without fields being completed.

Here's the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" id ="popup">

$(document).ready(function() {


$("#lightboxRegister").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});

    $("#lightboxRegister").click(function() {
        if(document.getElementById("title-vis").value ==""){
            alert("You need to enter a book title.");
            self.close();
        }
        if(document.getElementById("abstract-vis").value ==""){
            alert("You need to enter a book abstract.");
            self.close();
        }
        if(document.getElementById("writtenby-vis").value ==""){
            alert("You need to enter a pen name.");
            self.close();
        }

        document.getElementById("title").value = document.getElementById("title-vis").value;
        document.getElementById("abstract").value = document.getElementById("abstract-vis").value;
        document.getElementById("writtenby").value = document.getElementById("writtenby-vis").value;

    });


  });
</script>
```

I can't get this pop up

```
$("#lightboxRegister").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
```

to work inside the click function:

```
 $("#lightboxRegister").click(function()
```

I tried right after I close the message for third filed put this:

```
$(this).colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'colorbox'

Any help on how  I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="lightboxRegister"> REGISTER FORM </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="open inline?" />
```

Here is jquery code:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $.colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", href: '#lightboxRegister'});
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/9QkmH/](http://jsfiddle.net/9QkmH/)

Comment: But I need to check the 3 fields first. How can I integrate this code into existing javascript?

Comment: @user1426542 Look at this example: [jsfiddle.net/9QkmH/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/9QkmH/1/)

Comment: [CODE IS HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/E34c4/) When I integrated into my code there's syntax errors.  $('#btn').click(function() greyed out.

Comment: @user1426542 This is button with `id="btn"`, posted code is normal, you can add html-murkup and I will check your code.

Comment: @user1426542 Your button is generated with php? Look at this example: [jsfiddle.net/E34c4/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/E34c4/4/)

Comment: Yes, that's the whole problem.  That page does other things as well. Can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

to open colorbox on demand just use this:

```
$.colorbox({...});
```

for e.g.:

```
$('.myButton').click(function() {
  alert('ok, lets open colorbox now!');
  $.colorbox({href: 'myUrl.html', width: 500});
});
```

Comment: I don't want to open in demand. I want to open after the fields have been completed.